# ContentExtraction of PDF file in solr using Apache Tika

Tags: java, search, pdf, solr, apache-tika

I am trying to index the PDF file in the solr using the following tutorial
http://wiki.apache.org/solr/ExtractingRequestHandler
But everytime i am firing the command

```
java -jar post.jar *.pdf
```

it says some org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Invalid UTF-8 middle byte 0xe3 Error
Kindly help me in indexing the PDF to solr server.Is there any other integration then tika which can help me.

Comment: What version of SOLR and Tika are you using? If you try using the Tika App (command line) directly, does that work?

Comment: Solr version is 4.4.0 and Tika is 1.4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Post.jar is just an utility to upload files to Solr.
Solr uses Extract handler so you need to provide as url. e.g.

```
java -Durl=http://localhost:8983/solr/update/extract?literal.id=1 -Dtype=application/pdf -jar post.jar 1.pdf
```

For encrpted files check [link](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/ExtractingRequestHandler#Encrypted_files)
For Password Protected Files check [link](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/ExtractingRequestHandler#Password_protected)

Comment: Thanks dude it works.But the same command does not able to help me in inserting the encrypted PDF.is there some command for that also

Comment: updated the asnwer. They might require additional jars to be included. you can check

Comment: I had a similar problem as the OP (+1). What is the different between specifying URL and specifying collection/core like `-Dc=mycore`?

Answer (score 0):

There is obviously some encoding issue here.

I remember doing something like this a few months ago, and it is fairly easy if you can write your own piece of Java code. These are mostly simple to write, and they work like a charm!

Comment: Well writing a java code will surely solves the problem but why to implement that if solr provides that feature in itself.Just i am not getting how to use that.