# Solr - Indexing error with UTF-8 characters

Tags: solr

I am 100% new to Solr. I installed solr-5.1 for Windows and followed the tutorial.

I need some direction as to what may have caused the error below, e.g. need to add config to core xml file, UTF-8 encoding problem, etc...

start solr with :] `solr.cmd -start`

create a core :] `solr create -c myExample`

index pdf files :] `jar -Dc=myexample -Dfiletypes=pdf -jar ../example/exampledocs/post.jar E:\solr_docs\*.pdf`

Errors:

```
SimplePostTool version 5.0.0

Posting files to [base] url http://localhost:8983/solr/myExample/update using content-type application/xml...
POSTing file Intrusion detection by machine learning.pdf to [base]
SimplePostTool: WARNING: Solr returned an error \#400 (Bad Request) for url: http://localhost:8983/solr/myExample/update
SimplePostTool: WARNING: Response: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<response><lst name="responseHeader">
<intname="status">400</int><intname="QTime">0</int>
</lst><lst name="error"><str name="msg">Invalid UTF-8 middle byte 0xe3 (at char
\#10, byte \#-1)</str><int name="code">400</int></lst>
</response>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [ContentExtraction of PDF file in solr using Apache Tika](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18767945/contentextraction-of-pdf-file-in-solr-using-apache-tika)

Answer (score 0):

You are feeding Solr a PDF file is if it were a text file. You need to configure and use a suitable URP chain to have Solr work with PDF files.

Comment: Thanks very much but where can I found the info on this URP chain configuration?

Comment: The solr documentation, of which there is a mountain. Start with, of course, http://lucene.apache.org/solr/.